# Connecting Logitech MX Anywhere 3S with USB dongle

Tags: usb, mouse, logitech, solaar

Trying to connect a Logitech MX Anywhere 3S via the ["unifying receiver"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Unifying_receiver), I

- disable bluetooth on the laptop,
- use Solaar,
- Unifying Receiver is shown, even with another mouse (trackball) connected,
- click "Pair new device"
- switch the mouse on and off

and nothing happens. I tried this now a gazillion times with differing combinations of when to switch the mouse on and trying selecting channels with the button on the bottom of the mouse, no deal.

Then I switch on bluetooth and connect the mouse explicitly via bluetooth. This works and the mouse shows up in Solaar, though logically not as a sub-element of the Unifying Receiver.

When I turn Bluetooth off, the mouse naturally disappears from Solaar again and trying to pair still does not work.

[This reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/logitech/comments/ughsbg/connect_mx_master_3_mouse_via_usb_receiver_after/) addresses the same problem but all suggestions come down to "use Solaar or the logitech software and re-pair", which is what just does not work (OK, I didn't try Logitech software as I don't have access to any Windows machine.)

Any suggestion how to further debug this (solaar -d shows nothing interesting), let alone solve this?

This is on `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"`.

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason: the two seem not to be compatible. The Logitech MX Anywhere 3S has the [Logi Bolt](https://www.logitech.com/de-de/products/mice/logi-bolt-usb-receiver.956-000008.html) logo not the [Unifying Receiver](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/products/mice/unifying-receiver-usb.910-005236.html) logo, so there is no wonder the two won't pair. This [answer on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/logitech/comments/148ylq4/comment/jo69sjx/) says the same.